# "No, except Allah's Book or the power of understanding" - Is Quran the only revelation?

Tags: quran, hadith, sunnah, uloom-al-hadith, revelation

In Sahih Bukhari,in the 3rd Book (كتاب العلم) in Chapter 39. (The writing of knowledge (باب كِتَابَةِ الْعِلْمِ), 111th Hadith states the following:

> Abu Juhaifa said, "I asked `Ali, 'Have you got any book (which has been revealed to the Prophet (ﷺ) apart from the Qur'an)?'` Ali replied, 'No, except Allah's Book or the power of understanding which has been bestowed (by Allah) upon a Muslim or what is (written) in this sheet of paper (with me).' Abu Juhaifa said, "I asked, 'What is (written) in this sheet of paper?' `Ali replied, it deals with The Diyya (compensation (blood money) paid by the killer to the relatives of the victim), the ransom for the releasing of the captives from the hands of the enemies, and the law that no Muslim should be killed in Qisas (equality in punishment) for the killing of (a disbeliever).
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ سَلاَمٍ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا وَكِيعٌ، عَنْ سُفْيَانَ، عَنْ مُطَرِّفٍ، عَنِ الشَّعْبِيِّ، عَنْ أَبِي جُحَيْفَةَ، قَالَ قُلْتُ لِعَلِيٍّ هَلْ عِنْدَكُمْ كِتَابٌ قَالَ لاَ، إِلاَّ كِتَابُ اللَّهِ، أَوْ فَهْمٌ أُعْطِيَهُ رَجُلٌ مُسْلِمٌ، أَوْ مَا فِي هَذِهِ الصَّحِيفَةِ‏.‏ قَالَ قُلْتُ فَمَا فِي هَذِهِ الصَّحِيفَةِ قَالَ الْعَقْلُ، وَفَكَاكُ الأَسِيرِ، وَلاَ يُقْتَلُ مُسْلِمٌ بِكَافِرٍ‏.‏

*"No, except Allah's Book"*. Does that mean the only revelation was the Quran and the Sunnah is not a revelation just the practical understanding of the Quran? Would not this information change the concept how we classify which Hadith is Sahih which is not?

Comment: Your quote of the hadith is incomplete, the full hadith quote is [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:111). I don't know how you've came to the conclusion that this hadith means that Qur'an is the only revelation and what's the relationship between this and the sunnah and classification of hadith, please elaborate!

Comment: Sorry, I added the full hadith qoute. How I came to the conclusion? 

"I asked Ali, 'Have you got any book (which has been revealed to the Prophet (ﷺ) apart from the Qur'an)?' Ali replied, 'No, except Allah's Book or the power of understanding which has been bestowed (by Allah) upon a Muslim or what is (written) in this sheet of paper (with me)."

That is what it says. "No, except Allah's Book".

Comment: The question is, what abu Juhaifa meant with revelation and how 'Ali interpreted it? Because we know that qur'an is the only revelation for Muslims, however hadith can also be understood as such since Allah says that the prophet only speaks the truth and not from his inclination. This hopefully shall be explained in a hadith interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

The Holy Quran is the only book that was compiled in the time of Ali (a.s). Hadith was written down much later. In this sense, the answer is true, but it doesn't say that  all revelation has to be contained in the Quran.

Both, Sunni and Shia scholars, assume that revelation is not only contained in the Quran but it can also be related orally, i.e. in Hadith. Those who categorically reject any revelation outside the Quran (strict Quranists) are a small minority.

It would somehow bite into the tail if you used a hadith to support the thesis that hadith has no value.

So, the answer is, no.

Comment: your answer shows that you are have a serious unclarity between hadith and between revelation outside Quran.

 You wrote "It would somehow bite into the tail if you used a hadith to support the thesis that hadith has no value.". --> can you please point out in my question where I was trying to show that hadith hs no value? Answer: you can't, I did not support such thesis.

Comment: you also wrote: "Those who categorically reject any revelation outside the Quran (strict Quranists) are a small minority."

This is false. Correction "Those who categorically reject any HADITH outside the Quran (strict Quranists) are a small minority."

Comment: I used a hadith to support the thesis that there is no revelation outside the Quran. It means I accept hadith. It means I am not Quranist. It means as a Quranist you reject hadith. But if you reject that there is revelation to the Prophet Mohammed (s.a.w) outside the Quran, but accept hadith which are not contradictory to the Quran, it means YOU ARE NOT A QURANIST!!!!!

Comment: May Allah guide you @Jeschu, and may Allah guide all the people here in this platform who are slandering our beloved Prophet (s.a.w.) with fabricated Ahadith.

Comment: There is certainly a good reason to be sceptical with contents that can't be known except by revelation and not mentioned in the Quran. But i.m.o., this hadith does not exclude this because the question was about written documents, and no hadith was written in that time.

Comment: It is just not true what you are writen, the question is NOT about written documents. It is about "Kitab" :

هَلْ عِنْدَكُمْ كِتَابٌ

This is how Allah refers to the Quran:

ذٰلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَۚۛ ف۪يهِۚۛ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّق۪ينَۙ

That was originally NOT a written physical book, but a recited revelation.

In the cited Hadith, Ali (r.a.) does not have a printed book, just some notes written on a SHEET OF PAPER:

مَا فِي هَذِهِ الصَّحِيفَةِ‏

He is referring to the revelation ("Kitab"):
 لاَ، إِلاَّ كِتَابُ اللَّهِ، أَوْ فَهْمٌ أُعْطِيَهُ رَجُلٌ مُسْلِمٌ،

Comment: Do you suppose that "kitab" should be translated as "revelation"?

Comment: yes,  or more accurately "revelead Book", "recited Book", "revelead Scripture", "recited Scripture" or it just can be  referred as "Book", "Scripture" or "Revelation". It should be translated exactly in the meaning how Allah uses the word Kitab in the Quran. For example:

Comment: ذَٰلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ

Comment: أَتَأْمُرُونَ النَّاسَ بِالْبِرِّ وَتَنْسَوْنَ أَنْفُسَكُمْ وَأَنْتُمْ تَتْلُونَ الْكِتَابَ

Comment: وَإِذْ آتَيْنَا مُوسَى الْكِتَابَ وَالْفُرْقَانَ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَهْتَدُونَ

Comment: وَمِنْهُمْ أُمِّيُّونَ لَا يَعْلَمُونَ الْكِتَابَ إِلَّا أَمَانِيَّ

Comment: أَفَتُؤْمِنُونَ بِبَعْضِ الْكِتَابِ وَتَكْفُرُونَ بِبَعْضٍ

Comment: وَلَقَدْ آتَيْنَا مُوسَى الْكِتَابَ وَقَفَّيْنَا مِنْ بَعْدِهِ بِالرُّسُلِ

Comment: وَلَمَّا جَاءَهُمْ كِتَابٌ مِنْ عِنْدِ اللَّهِ مُصَدِّقٌ لِمَا مَعَهُمْ

Comment: نَبَذَ فَرِيقٌ مِنَ الَّذِينَ أُوتُوا الْكِتَابَ

Comment: كِتَابَ اللَّهِ وَرَاءَ ظُهُورِهِمْ

Comment: مَا يَوَدُّ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا مِنْ أَهْلِ الْكِتَابِ وَلَا الْمُشْرِكِينَ أَنْ يُنَزَّلَ عَلَيْكُمْ مِنْ خَيْرٍ مِنْ رَبِّكُمْ

Comment: وَدَّ كَثِيرٌ مِنْ أَهْلِ الْكِتَابِ لَوْ يَرُدُّونَكُمْ مِنْ بَعْدِ إِيمَانِكُمْ كُفَّارًا

Comment: وَقَالَتِ النَّصَارَىٰ لَيْسَتِ الْيَهُودُ عَلَىٰ شَيْءٍ وَهُمْ يَتْلُونَ الْكِتَابَ

Comment: @Code-G : I have opend a chatroom https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151955/alkitab to continue this discussion, I think it is interesting but it exceeds the frame of comments. I hope you can join.

Comment: @CodeG Seems that I can't invite you for technical reasons, (possibly as you have never been in a SE chatroom before) but maybe you can just join.